# The configuration section 'appSettings' has an unexpected declaration

Tags: c#, app-config

I am facing a problem with my `app.config` file in c#

Most of time service can read section `<appsetting>`, but sometimes an error occurs below.

This problem occurred intermittently, so it is hard to find the cause of the error:

> "The configuration section 'appSettings' has an unexpected declaration."

My `app.config` is as follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
 <system.runtime.remoting>
 <application>
  <channels>
    <channel ref="tcp" port="5555">
      <serverProviders>
        <formatter ref="binary" />
      </serverProviders>
    </channel>
   </channels>
  <service>
    <wellknown mode="SingleCall" type="Sample, Sample.BSL" objectUri="Sample.BSL.Common.bin" />
  </service>
 </application>
 <customErrors mode="Off" />
 </system.runtime.remoting>
 <appSettings>
 <add key="KEY_1" value="Sample.Service.exe.config"></add>
 <add key="KEY_2" value="VALUE"/>
  <add key="KEY_3" value="VALUE"></add>
 <add key="KEY_4" value="VALUE"></add>
 <add key="KEY_5" value="VALUE"></add>
 <add key="KEY_6" value="VALUE"></add>
 <add key="KEY_7" value="VALUE"></add>
 <add key="KEY_8" value="VALUE"></add>
 <add key="KEY_9.ServiceUri" value="" />
 <add key="KEY_10" value="D:\VALUE\Log\Sample.Service" />
</appSettings>
<startup>
 <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
</startup>
<system.web>
 <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
 <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
   <providers>
     <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
   </providers>
 </membership>
 <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
   <providers>
     <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
       </providers>
     </roleManager>
   </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: I wonder if it's something to do with `<add key="" value=""></add>` vs `<add key="" value="" />` (for XML I think both are correct, but maybe it's fussy? Try the latter)

Comment: it's also missing the usual `encoding="utf-8" ?` at the top in the `<?xml` tag

Comment: I changed all keys to  "<add key="" value="" />" But it still occured.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Update the `<add />` elements of your `<appSettings />`  like so to resolve the issue:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="KEY_1" value="Sample.Service.exe.config"/>
  <add key="KEY_2" value="VALUE"/>
  <add key="KEY_3" value="VALUE"/>
  <add key="KEY_4" value="VALUE"/>
  <add key="KEY_5" value="VALUE"/>
  <add key="KEY_6" value="VALUE"/>
  <add key="KEY_7" value="VALUE"/>
  <add key="KEY_8" value="VALUE"/>
  <add key="KEY_9.ServiceUri" value="" />
  <add key="KEY_10" value="D:\VALUE\Log\Sample.Service" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! But I changed all keys to  "<add key="" value="" />" But it still occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a threading issue. I can reproduce the issue with the following code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running test....");
        
        string value = "";
        var t1 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++)
            {
                value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test"];
            }
        });

        var t2 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
            }
        });

        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);

        Console.WriteLine("DONE");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We never got around to solve this issue but from our monitoring tool, it indicates that our service is overloaded with jobs and caused the threading issue mentioned by Jon Mitchell.

We solved it by spinning up another instance of the service to distribute the workload. Perhaps this will help others that faced similar issue.